# sending arguments with onserverClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i send argument with onserverclick event

Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  ID="platformHyperLink" runat="server" class="platformElementHL" onserverclick='<%# platformHyperLink_Click("+Eval("PLATFORM_ID").ToString()+")"%>' />click</a>
```

server code:

```
protected void platformHyperLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    findDevice.Visible = true;
    LinkButton lk = sender as LinkButton;

    ClearAndHide(false);
    findDevice.Visible = true;
    DeviceSelectedValueHiddenField.Value = null;
    ModelSelectedValueHiddenField.Value = null;
    OsSelectedValueHiddenField.Value = null;

    Label PlatformNameLabel = lk.NamingContainer.FindControl("PlatformNameLabel") as Label;
    platformName = PlatformNameLabel.Text;
    SelectYourDeviceLabel.Visible = true;
    platformID = Convert.ToInt32(lk.CommandArgument.ToString());
    DataTable DT = WebsiteDataHelper.GetPlatformDevice(platformID);

    if (DT.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        DeviceListBox.Visible = false;
       // DeviceNoDataFound.Visible = true;
        SelectYourDeviceLabel.Visible = false;

    }
    else
    {
        SelectYourDeviceLabel.Visible = true;
        DeviceListBox.Visible = true;
       // DeviceNoDataFound.Visible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string text = DT.Rows[i]["DEVICE_NAME"].ToString();
            string val = DT.Rows[i]["DEVICE_ID"].ToString();
            RadListBoxItem item = new RadListBoxItem(text, val);
            DeviceListBox.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that i can't access platformHyperlink and i don't know why please help me

Comment: Why would you not use an `asp:LinkButton`?

Comment: bcs i don't want it to post back the page

Answer (score 0):

To call server side methods without posting back, you need to use Ajax.

You can take a look at UpdatePanels or PageMethods.

I think what you are looking for is PageMethods.

This [blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/04/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods.aspx) should get you started

```
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]
public static string GetLabelText()
{
    return "Hello";
}

<script type="text/javascript">    
      function InsertLabelData() {    
          PageMethods.GetLabelText(onSuccess, onFailure);    
      }   

      function onSuccess(result) {    
          var lbl = document.getElementById('lbl');    
          lbl.innerHTML = result;    
      }

      function onFailure(error) {    
          alert(error);    
      }    
      InsertLabelData();    
    </script>
```

Comment: that's not what i'm looking for

Comment: Then what is it that you are looking for?

Comment: how can i access my server side function i want to understand why i can't access it

Comment: A server side function is available on the server. you need to send a request to the server to execute it. Browsers do not process server side code.

Comment: i understand that's why i'm using on serverclick event

Comment: The `ServerClick` event cause a `PostBack` to the server. So the result is the same as what I have provided in the answer.